# how to make an .jsp invoke a method using eclipse Google app engine

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine, call

hello iam having problem invoking function in my project ![enter image description here]

```
<form action="register" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">UserID:</td><td><input type="text" name="Id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Name :</td><td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><input type="button"  value="sumbitk"></td>     
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <hr>
```

`$`

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws IOException {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
        //RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
        String id=req.getParameter("id");
        String name=req.getParameter("name");
        String password=req.getParameter("pass");
        System.out.println("user id : "+id+" name    "+name+" pass "+password);
        resp.sendRedirect("/index.html");
        //dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
        //dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
    }
```

}

i made form action on register and calls function post but it not seems to work when i click sumbit i dont know why .

Answer (score 1):

First try write "submit" correctly in last input, if don't work try chage the type of last input to "submit" instead "button"